# How do I replace elements of string from left-to-right to right-to-left in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my HTML I have a string of 5 numbers. When a "delete" button is clicked, numbers are replaced by dashes in left to right order. Yay it works! But how do I replace the numbers in *right to left* order?

```js
$("#deleteButton").click(function() {
  var str = document.getElementById("dashes").innerHTML;
  var str = str.replace(/[0-9]/, "-");
  document.getElementById("dashes").innerHTML = str;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashes">123456789</div>
<button id="deleteButton">delete</button>
```

Comment: Your existing code should already be replacing digits in left-to-right order; for example, if `dashes` contains `--345`, then unless I'm really missing something, a click on `deleteButton` should update it to `---45`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want? Because it also looks to me like it works left-to-right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to identify the right-most digit rather than the left-most digit (a regular expression searches from left-to-right by default). Note that you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` for less syntax noise. One option is to use

```
/\d(?=\D*$)/
```

That is, match a digit, lookahead for any number of non-digit characters, followed by the end of the string.

```js
$("#deleteButton").click(function() {
  var str = document.getElementById("dashes").innerHTML;
  str = str.replace(/\d(?=\D*$)/, "-");
  document.getElementById("dashes").innerHTML = str;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashes">123456789</div>
<button id="deleteButton">delete</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for..Thank You,  CertainPerformance!

Comment: Is there a way in my CSS to keep the dashes from moving when it's replaced by a number?

Comment: How to do this but replacing by 0 instead of dash?

Comment: @rodrigoum Replace `"-"` with `"0"` ?